# GWT+DataGrid freeze/unfreeze row selection

Tags: gwt, datagrid

So I have implemented a SingleSelectionModel to select only single row in the DataGrid.

```
final SingleSelectionModel<Entity> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<>(keyProvider);
```

And I've created a checkbox that should freeze/unfreeze row selection.
In other words, when the checkbox is checked, current row must be selected (blue highlighted cuz I'm using the SingleSelectionModel), and user should not be able to select another row via keyboard/mice while checkbox is checked. The row still must stay selected.

```
// disable row selection using selection model
    disableSelection.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
            // do stuff, any suggestions guys?
        }
    });
```

Maybe using NoSelectionModel, or adding a selectionChangeHandler to the existing selection model.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
NoSelectionModel<Entity> noSelectionModel = new NoSelectionModel<Entity();
...
disableSelection.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        myDataGrid.setSelectionModel(event.getValue() ? noSelectionModel : selectionModel);
    }
});
```

Comment: While I'm using NoSelectionModel, row selection is not available for user, it's true, but before this I have to set selected row without a possibility to change the selection, but the NoSelectionModel cancels this selection at all :( Is it possible?

Comment: You can simply add a style to your selected row which makes it look "selected" - this is what DataGrid does when you click on a row. Another approach is to keep using SingleSelectionModel, but revert the selection if a flag is set. I don't know if it will be noticeable to a user.